# How can you make a C program add line numbers to a file's contents. E.g., "1. #include <stdio.h> 2. #include <stdlib.h>", etc.?

Tags: c, count, addition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int process_stream(FILE *fpntr);
char *fgetline(FILE *fpntr);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    FILE *fpntr;
    char filename[100], c;
    int a = 0;

    printf("Please enter a file name/directory: \n");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    fpntr = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fpntr == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    //read contents from file
    c = fgetc(fpntr);
    while (c != EOF){

        printf ("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(fpntr);
        if (c == '\n')

            {
                a++;
                printf("%d", a);
    }}

    fclose(fpntr);
    return 0;
    exit (0);
}
```

Comment: You seem to have the basic idea, now implement it.

Comment: Start withchanging the type of `c` to `int` so that let it distinguish valid characters with EOF.

Comment: That is where I am struggling. I have attempted many things but get random strings of letters and numbers in a few of my attempts. I have also been returned continuous "c". I will continue to read; however, I am still a very fresh programmer.

Comment: Do I need to set the value of c?

Comment: If you have a specific problem or error then please focus on and ask about that by providing those details. SO questions need to be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, implement just as what you says.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    FILE *fptr;
    char filename[100];
    int c;
    int lineNumber = 1;

    printf("Please enter a file name/directory: \n");
    scanf("%99s", filename);

    // Open the file
    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    //read contents from file
    // While ((c = read a character) is not EOF)
    while ((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF){
        // If (c is \n)
        if (c == '\n') {
            // Print "lineNumber", then increment it
            printf("%d. ", lineNumber);
            lineNumber++;
        }
        // Print c
        printf ("%c", c);
    // End while
    }

    // Close the file
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this code won't work well and its output is

```
#include <stdio.h>1. 
#include <stdlib.h>2. 
int hoge;3. 
int fuga;4.
```

when the input file is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int hoge;
int fuga;
```

The fault is that you are printing line numbers at the end of lines.
They should be at the beginning of lines.
I would use a flag that indicates beginning of lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    FILE *fptr;
    char filename[100];
    int c;
    int lineNumber = 1;
    int isBeginningOfLine = 1;

    printf("Please enter a file name/directory: \n");
    scanf("%99s", filename);

    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    //read contents from file
    while ((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF){
        if (isBeginningOfLine) {
            print("%d. ", lineNumber);
            isBeginningOfLine = 0;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
            lineNumber++;
            isBeginningOfLine = 1;
        }
        printf ("%c", c);
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I get

```
1. #include <stdio.h>
2. #include <stdlib.h>
3. int hoge;
4. int fuga;
```

Comment: This helped to clarify the logic behind what I did not understand, thank you!